# ClientHandlerException using the latest (2.10.0 to 3.1.0) Java DocuSignAPI

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am facing a problem using the Java DocuSignAPI. The code works fine with version 2.9.0, but with later versions I get a ClientHandlerException. I received the accessToken following the instructions for OAuth on the DocuSign web page. I also followed the code snippet to create a simple envelope.

As mentioned, the code snippet works fine with the version 2.9.0 and previous versions. What I already found out is, that in the constructor of the ApiClient there is an OAuth setup with null parameters.

```
authentications = new HashMap<String, Authentication>();
authentications.put("docusignAccessCode", new OAuth(null, null, null));
```

This runs in a NullPointerException in the OAuth.updateAccessToken function. No idea what I am doing wrong. Here is a simple example for getting account information.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
        apiClient.setBasePath("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
        apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization",
                "Bearer [accessToken]");

        try {
            AccountsApi accountsApi = new AccountsApi(apiClient);
            AccountInformation accountInformation = accountsApi.getAccountInformation("[AccountId]");
            System.out.println(accountInformation);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

The exception message is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException
    at com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.updateAccessToken(OAuth.java:111)
    at com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.applyToParams(OAuth.java:99)
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.updateParamsForAuth(ApiClient.java:1209)
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.getAPIResponse(ApiClient.java:1094)
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:1158)
    at com.docusign.esign.api.AccountsApi.getAccountInformation(AccountsApi.java:851)
    at com.docusign.esign.api.AccountsApi.getAccountInformation(AccountsApi.java:805)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.updateAccessToken(OAuth.java:109)
    ... 7 more
```

With version 2.9.0 I get the expected account information:

```
class AccountInformation {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Crimson, version 3 and above of the SDK is a completely new version released to support our v2.1 API. It has breaking changes and you cannot just upgrade your code to use it without making changes to the code. If you share your code here - we could try to help. I would also suggest trying latest SDK with simple sample code step by step if you prefer to start this way. 
You could continue to work with 2.9 if you have it working ok as well. That would remain supported.

Comment: Hello Inbar, thank you for your reply. I would really love to use your latest SDK. Unfortunately all your code samples referenced by the DocuSign web page using the old version 2.9.0. It would help me a lot, if I can just run the simple example I mentioned in the question. Is there a different authentication flow i don't get yet?

Comment: We're in the process of updating it. Should be ready soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on 10/14/2019, just after returning from API:World. I resolved the issue by using the docusign-esign-java-2.9.0.jar instead of the docusign-esign-java-3.2.0.jar.

I am following verbatim the code example on https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email  (using my account and OAuth access token).

The C# examples work fine.  I used NuGet for the libraries.  For Java, I used Maven.

This should be pretty easy to test on the Docusign end in terms of reproducing the issue.